# Is there way to get system uuid from python that runs from non-root account?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, root

I am particularly interested in system uuid, I know I can get it from dmidecode output(via subprocess) but that would require root privileges I assume. Is there a better way of doing this ? I tried googling it but didnt find any concrete answer

```
prompt# sudo dmidecode
Handle 0x0100, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
        Manufacturer: QEMU
        Product Name: Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996)
        Version: pc-i440fx-trusty
        Serial Number: Not Specified
        UUID: 0F236341-588C-CEBB-D054-BD239B311E2F <<<<<<<<<<
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        SKU Number: Not Specified
```

Comment: You can probably find the source for dmidecode somewhere, given it's Linux.  How do they do it internally?

Comment: `dmidecode` needs sudo rights, you can also get the info in /sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid (ubuntu), also sudo needed. `lshal` would work without root privileges, but then hal/dbus is required. You can also have /var/lib/dbus/machine-id (other format). The source code for dmidecode can be found under https://github.com/mirror/dmidecode/blob/master/dmidecode.c

Comment: for understanding dmidecode implementation, this could be helpful: https://www.dmtf.org/standards/smbios

Answer (score 0):

root:

```
chmod a+r /sys/firmware/dmi/tables/DMI
dmidecode -s system-uuid
```

other user command:

```
dmidecode -t 1  < /sys/firmware/dmi/tables/DMI | awk "$1=="UUID:"{print $2}"
```

docs link:

- https://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_3.3.0.pdf